# How can I use a built-in webcam in lubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: lubuntu, webcam

How do I use the Acer Aspire One netbook's webcam in lubuntu 18.04.1?
And how do I view the webcam's output to check it's OK? A cutout at a corner of the screen would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install **cheese** to use your camera..Open your terminal and type

```
sudo apt install cheese
```

You can then use your camera..Hope this will help you.

Thank you..

Comment: Thanks, cloud.009 :-)
Installing **cheese** also installs the **gnome-video-effects package**. Now:
(1) **cheese** shows a video selfie (= camera test).
(2) When **cheese** isn't running, I can initiate a Skype video call.
(3) Privacy: I don't yet know how to switch the webcam off...

Comment: use 'killall cheese' then it will be closed.